# web.py markdown global name 'markdown' is not defined

Tags: web.py

Im trying to use markdown together with Templetor in web.py but I can't figure out what Im missing

Documentation is here http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor#builtins

```
import markdown

t_globals = {
    'datestr': web.datestr,
    'markdown': markdown.markdown
}
render = web.template.render(globals=t_globals)

class Blog:
    def GET(self, post_slug):
        """ Render single post """
        post = BlogPost.get(BlogPost.slug == post_slug)

        render = web.template.render(base="layout")
        return render.post({
                "blogpost_title": post.title,
                "blogpost_content": post.content,
                "blogpost_teaser": post.teaser
            })
```

here is how I try to use markdown inside the post.html template

```
$def with (values)
$var title: $values['blogpost_title']

<article class="post">
  <div class="post-meta">
    <h1 class="post-title">$values['blogpost_title']</h1>
  </div>

  <section class="post-content">
    <a name="topofpage"></a>
        $:markdown(values['blogpost_content'])
  </section>
```

But Im getting this exception

> type 'exceptions.NameError' at
>   /blog/he-ll-want-to-use-your-yacht-and-i-don-t-want-this-thing-smelling-like-fish/
>   global name 'markdown' is not defined

Comment: your passing globals to template is fine. Check to make sure you're actually attempting to render your template with your defined `render` which knows about the t_globals. ... Edit to add more code above if you're still having problems.

Comment: I've added more code do show the view which uses the render method

Comment: That's it: either don't re-initialize `render` within Blog.GET, or add `globals=t_globals` to the call in Blog.GET -- you can't do both.

Comment: of cause! Im re-initializing to set the base /facepalm - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-initializing `render`, once in global scope setting `globals` and once within `Blog.GET` setting `base`. Do it only once!